# On Tomcat 5.5, how do I increase the maximum fileupload size?

Tags: tomcat, upload

I have a web app on tomcat that needs to upload files up to 1 meg in size. The default tomcat 5.5 configuration is 100k. How do I increase it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the tomcat config was fine. The web app is using Spring CommonsMultipartResolver and the maxUploadSize property was given a value that was too small.